# Is there a way to insert data into an sql table using spark jdbc WITHOUT inserting duplicates AND losing already existing data?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a spark dataframe into a postgresql table by using df.write.jdbc.
The problem is, I want to make sure to not lose existing data already inside the table (Using SaveMode.Append) but also making sure to avoid inserting duplicate data already inserted into it.

1. So, if I use SaveMode.Overwrite:

-The table gets dropped losing all previous data

2. If I use SaveMode.Append:

- The table doesn't get dropped but the duplicate records get inserted.
- If I use this mode together with a primary key already into the db (that would provide the unique constraint) it returns an error.

Is there some kind of option to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to filter out existing records, that means an additional read to get existing ids, and a fitler operation on data to append.. but it does the job for me.

There's I think a more complex solution in this post:

https://medium.com/@thomaspt748/how-to-upsert-data-into-a-relational-database-using-apache-spark-part-1-python-version-b43b9761bbf2

Maybe late, but just went into this.